# Cheapest way to surface Aurora MySQL Serverless data to a public URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-connection, aws-aurora-serverless

Is there a best/cheapest way to provide a public URL that enables users to query an AWS RDS Aurora MySQL Serverless database?

I've seen multiple recommendations, including:

(1) an EC2 instance that's always on (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/TUT_WebAppWithRDS.html);

(2) building a Serverless application (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/query-your-aws-database-from-your-serverless-application/).

Ideally there would be no required oversight (e.g., no backend AWS user would have to "turn on" the EC2 instance when someone wanted to access the site), and no lag time -- if a user entered the public URL in their browser it would immediately populate, and they would be able to enter queries into a displayed input bar and see query results.

Is it fine/relatively cheap to just have an EC2 instance always running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for completely serverless architecture. You can go for static web site hosting on S3, some blackened logic if required on lambda with serverless aurora. Here is an example architecture from AWS, just replace DynamoDB with Aurora for your purpose

[image]

Follow this for further understanding : [Build a Serverless Web Application](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/)

Comment: This was the kind of tutorial I was looking for -- thank you!